# How to you get the information from an entity that is referenced with a foreign key within a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table which has a foreign key within to gather the colour from another table. I am wondering is how can I get that information and display it using MVC Razor.

Here is the query,

```
SELECT * FROM tblproducts
```

This then displays all of the relevant information stored within that entity except the information that is stored on a different table which is linked using a foreign key.

If anyone can help that would be great!

Thanking you in advance

Callum

Comment: Google `SQL JOINs` then find a good book on introductory SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join from tblproducts to the colour table using the foreign key column, and the referenced column in the other table

```
SELECT * FROM tblproducts t INNER JOIN other_table ot 
ON t.table_fk = ot.colour_sk
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your Help, It is extremely appreciated